# Is there a more efficient way to create an x% chance of something happening?

Tags: java, random

Usually, when I want a chance of something happening I use a random number, then an if statement to check for a specific outcome, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    public boolean chance(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int chance = Random(100)+1; //For a 1/100 chance
        if(chance == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Are there more efficient ways to do this in java, like a java library method, or am I stuck with creating it every time I want to use a percent chance.

Comment: What is inefficient about it?

Comment: Does that actually work? If you don't seed the RNG wont you get the same series each time? So by creating the Random inside the method it actually makes it not so random? Edit: javadocs say the `()` CTOR uses a seed likely to be distinct from other instances. Still. In terms of efficiency, creating a new random instance for one number is not necessary. Perhaps use `Math.random()` or keep the `Random` instance around.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: What if x is 37, how is your code adapt to that?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `x` represents a percent chance:

```
public static boolean chance(int x) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100) < x;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

how about:

```
import java.util.Random;
class Oink {
    private Random rnd;
    Boolean chance() {
        return (rnd.nextDouble()<0.01);
    }
}
```